# What is the best way to benchmark Hazelcast's speed to data retrieval, comparing with direct DB calls / RESTful service calls?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hazelcast

**Background:** My team has been maintaining a mix of classic ASP/ASP.NET apps for over a decade. My company recently had a re-org in which teams and managers were either laid off or swapped around. My new manager is pushing for a refactoring of our entire app portfolio over the coming year or two to Java/Spring-boot to meet company infrastructural standards. Most of our apps today perform ETL tasks via sprocs from MSSQL or Oracle SQL databases, with a few connecting to APIs via SOAP and REST respectively.

**Goal:** As part of this rewrite, I've been asked to help make a decision about how we handle data retrieval for our apps and to determine if there are any opportunities for improvement. I want to try out Hazelcast (server) and "prove" it out-performs traditional data-retrieval methods like direct DB / REST calls.

**Question:** What would be the best approach for achieving my goal (benchmarking Hazelcast)? My initial idea is creating a proof of concept with Java & Spring to test a.) the average speed of a direct DB call, b.) the average speed of a RESTful API call, and c.) the average speed of retrieval from Hazelcast. I would make sure the record set is consistent across all three tests. Is this the right approach, or am I over/under complicating it? Is there already something built out I can use to demonstrate the same?

(Note, **I understand Hazelcast is not meant to replace the original source of record**, but provide data caching for quicker retrieval of subsequent calls. I want proof that it is indeed quicker to retrieve from the cache rather than just doing another DB/API call).

Answer (score 1):

This is also covered on the same question on Google Group - https://groups.google.com/g/hazelcast/c/Q6LpR8o6qII